# Stood vs Stayed in a specific case

Tags: verbs

I've used the search function but couldn't find a specific case like this one.
Which one is the right one and why?

1) These teachings stood untouched throughout generations.

2) These teachings stayed untouched throughout generations.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: When you ask yourself if you want to say that the teachings were able to *stand* or to *stay* for a long time, you will know how to to put that in the past tense.

Comment: Stay... as in they endured for a long time, and not stand as in standing up.

Comment: In "my advice stands" I would mean that is has not changed. I take your first sentence to mean that the teachings were used but remained the same, and the second one to mean that they were, perhaps, hidden away.

Comment: Can you first explain what you mean by 'untouched'? Wouldn't 'remained' work better? 'Remained inviolate'?

Comment: The intention it to show that these teachings remained uncorrupted and  immaculate throughout generations.

Comment: Maybe you want to say the teachings did not move around (stayed). But probably you want to say they remained solidly with authority, stood the test of time, stood firm. As @WeatherVane offers in *advice stands*, you want *the teachings stood*. Stands means more than stand up (arise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) *These teachings stood untouched throughout generations.*
>
> 2) *These teachings stayed untouched throughout generations.*

Neither one is idiomatic; *throughout* is incorrect with an indefinite temporal phrase like *generations*. If you really want to use *throughout*, you need a definite term like *the middle ages* or *the sixteenth century*. With an indefinite like *generations*, the prepositions should be *for*.

- 3) *These teachings stood untouched for generations.*
- 4) *These teachings stayed untouched for generations.*

Both (3) and (4) are grammatical. Of course, they don't mean the same precise thing, because they use different verbs with different meanings, and these verbs instantiate different metaphors.

- *stood* is the irregular past tense of the verb ***stand***
- *stayed* is the regular past tense of the verb ***stay***

Both *stand* and *stay* refer to continuation of the subject's physical location and orientation, so they **can** refer to the same phenomenon (though they don't always). But, in these examples, the subject (*these teachings*) is not a physical object, but an abstract reference, and therefore has no physical orientation to refer to.

This is a **metaphor**. And it fits both verbs. What is being said is that the teachings persisted historically (as teachings, part of the culture, whatever it is in this context) for (some unspecified number of) generations. And that persistence of an abstract idea can be metaphorically *standing*

- *Democracy stands as a barrier to tyranny*

or simply *remaining*

- *Democracy stays firmly opposed to tyranny*

depending on which *`ST-`* metaphor one chooses. There are [a **LOT** of words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/st.pdf) with this phonosemantic constellation, and they come from [a large assortment of *ST*-initial PIE roots](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/st-PIEroots.pdf), all having similar semantics.

Comment: Precisely. Excellent explanation. You'd be a heck of an editor! Thank you very much.